# Insert slide(s) before or after currently selected slide in PowerPoint

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, office-js, powerpoint-addins

I have a function that fetches an API, that converts PowerPoint presentations into base64 strings. After getting the response object, I want to insert the slides into the current presentation, specifically **after** the currently selected slide.

The way I thought of doing it is what the documentation says: get the selected slide ID and use it in the target slide ID option. The documentation introduces a function, getSelectedSlideIndex(), to get the ID of the selected slide, but it throws a Rich API Promise error. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/add-slides

```
export async function getImageAsBase64String() {
  // API call that fetches presentations as base64 strings
  // ..
  const results = await response.json();

  await PowerPoint.run(async (context) => {
    const selectedID = await getSelectedSlideIndex();

    context.presentation.insertSlidesFromBase64(results[0].presentations[0], {  
      targetSlideId: selectedID,
    });          
      await context.sync();
  });
}
```

Is there a specific format for the selected ID? Ideally, I want to select a slide, press a button and the new slides (as base64 strings) are inserted after the selected slide.

Comment: Why are you using the getSelectedSlideIndex method for adding slides instead of the getSelectedSlideID method for inserting slides? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/insert-slides-into-presentation#insert-slides-with-insertslidesfrombase64

Comment: That was it. I don't know why it didn't register that I needed the ID not the index. Thank you. A small follow-up: instead of getting the currently selected slide, is there a way to get a slide ID based on text in the slide? Example: I generate a slide with title "Team"; I want to find that specific slide ID, then insert my other slides after it.

Comment: That should really be a separate Stack question, but I *think* you can iterate over all the slides and all the text shapes in each slide till you find the one with "Teams", then select that slide and use getSelectedSlideID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Turning a comment into an answer)

Use the getSelectedSlideID method for **inserting** slides as described in [Insert slides](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/insert-slides-into-presentation#insert-slides-with-insertslidesfrombase64).

The getSelectedSlideIndex method is for **adding** slides.